# Using view-camera-set active object as camera is zooming in to the object as i am new can someone explain why its hapening

Tags: modeling, camera

[Using view-camera-set active object as camera is zooming in to the object as i am new can someone explain why its happening. Kindly  check this video.](https://clipchamp.com/watch/ZfV6zjLDP4S)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide some context and explanation by verbally describing your issue, don't just post, images, videos, files to download, or links to external sites. See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are choosing *Set Active Object as Camera* from the menu. When you have no active object currently selected, this refers automatically to the last active object (unless it is deleted).

The last active object in your case was the "Icosphere", this is indicated by showing the name in the top left of the *3D Viewport* and highlighting the object symbol in the *Outliner*. When you set the icosphere as camera, your view jumps to the origin of it, which is in the center of the mesh.

[image: last active object]

Comment: Hi ,Thank you for clearing my doubt may i know the exact use for this option as u are well experienced it will be helpful and while searching youtube abou this issue i found that by going to view - Local camera- camera the problem was solved .But i dont know what it is used for though thanks you.

Comment: First of all if you would have selected a camera as last active object, you could have switched to that camera which I guess was what you wanted to do originally. The other thing is, for example you have a character in your scene and you want the camera to be placed where his head is. You can then either place a camera on the head and parent it to the head, or you can simply make the head the camera. In this case you can either disable camera visibility for the head object so that it does not block the view from inside or set the clipping start to be in front of the head to make it disappear.

Comment: However, the camera view is always pointing in object's -Z direction, so this is probably not very practical in many cases. If you cannot imagine a use case for this function, it does not matter, then it's simply not made for you. There are other things in Blender which I don't use, but others might.

Comment: Thanks understood